# Ограничить максимальное перемещение GridSpliter

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос сводится к тому, как ограничить свободу движения GridSpliter?

Простой пример:
Есть форма, на ней Grid из 4-х строк. В первой данные, во второй сплитер, в третьей данные, в четвертой кнопки.
Задал минимальные размеры для 1,3 строк. для 2-й автоматический размер, для 4-й фиксированый.

Так вот, когда двигаю сплиттер по вертикали, 3-я строка доходит до своего минимального размера, и перестает уменьшаться, но сплиттер все еще можно дальше тянуть вниз, тем самым 3-я и 4-я строка просто начинают сдвигаться вниз, причем даже за видимые границы формы. 
Как ограничить свободу движения сплиттера, что если дальше некуда сдвигаться компонентам, то и хватит на этом, пора останавливаться...

Спасибо за помощь.

**UPD:**

Есть подозрение, что проблема в битности ОС. На работе попробовал под Windows7 x86 MSVS2010 Express x86 Проблема не наблюдается

Дома под Windows7 x64 MSVS2010 Profession x64 проблема наблюдается

Одно только уточнение, одинаковый код набирался руками по памяти, могло что-то различаться, но не думаю, что мог ошибиться.

---

Приложение №1

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0">Тра-та-та</TextBox>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></GridSplitter>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2">О-ла-ла</TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="3">OK</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Приложение №2

Старт программы:

[image]

Сдвигаю сплиттер на максимум:

[image]

Сдвигаю сплиттер дальше, чем должно было быть:

[image]

Вопрос, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем спасибо.
Нашел ответ. Проблема не в битности, а в установках высоты строк. Грид дурит (хотя говорят, что так и задумано) при работе со смежными строками высотой auto. В итоге нужно, чтоб по обе стороны было две строки с высотой "*".

Ответ честно прочитан на stackoverflow: [Stop Gridsplitter stretching content beyond window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879584/stop-gridsplitter-stretching-content-beyond-window)